# How do add drop down menu for the folium map?

Tags: python, gis, geopandas, folium

For example, given the various months columns containing temperatures per specific region, how can I change the heatmap based on each month using drop down menu? I already have a map built using the geodataframe.explore(column = 'col_name').

Thanks!

Comment: I think you're getting a lot of downvotes because this is an extremely broad question. You might get a better response if you post the code you have, explain more specifically what you're trying to do (e.g. are you building a webpage? or trying to use widgets in jupyterlab?) and explain what you've tried so far.

Comment: Hello, good point. I would have posted a code if I knew what code to use. Geopandas is totally new to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working in jupyterlab, this is pretty easy! You can combine a [`ipywidgets.Output`](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Output%20Widget.html) widget with a [`ipywidgets.Dropdown`](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20List.html#Dropdown) to set up your canvas, then capture the follium map with the output. You then need to link them by adding an event handler.

```py
import geopandas as gpd
import ipywidgets
from IPython.display import HTML, display

df = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))

out = ipywidgets.Output(layout={'border': '1px solid black'})

w = ipywidgets.Dropdown(
    options=df.columns.values.tolist(),
    value=df.columns.values[0],
    description='Column:',
    disabled=False,
)

def on_dropdown_change(change):
    out.clear_output()
    with out:
        display(df.explore(w.value, cmap="Blues"))

w.observe(on_dropdown_change, names='value')
display(w)

with out:
    display(df.explore(df.columns[0], cmap="Blues"))

out
```

[image: folium/leaflet world map with dropdown widget for selecting columns]